# Are the words "network packet" and "network package" interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

"packet" and "package" are synonyms when we refer to mailings, but does the same apply to "[network packet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_packet)"?

My co-worker frequently says: "network package". It's like nails on a chalkboard to me, but is it correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Packet* and *package* are certainly different in IT terms.

A *packet* is a small piece of data, that needs to be combined with other packets to create a whole. This is how data is transmitted over a network, by breaking it into packets of a few bytes: http://www.computeruser.com/dictionary/packet/

A *package* refers to an entire piece of software, that can be installed and operated by a user: http://www.computeruser.com/dictionary/software-package/

A software package would be broken into packets to be sent over a network, and the packets would then be reassembled into a package at the destination.

*Network package* is technically incorrect, although the meaning can be easily inferred.

Comment: Yup. If I hear “network package” out of context, I'll think it means the component of the operating system or application that contains the code to handle networking.